# How to split a string include some points coordinate in java?

Tags: java

I have a string as follow and I want to get as output. How can I do?

Input:

```
String strconverted = "MULTIPOINT Z (116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582,116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997)";
```

output:

```
String pnt1= "116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582"

String pnt2= "116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997"
```

Please note that may "MULTIPOINT" has more than two point.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for string splitting is

```
String strconverted = "(116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582,116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997)";
strconverted = strconverted.replace(")", "");
strconverted = strconverted.replace("(", "");

String[] parts = strconverted.split(",");

// parts[0] =  "116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582"
// parts[0] =  "116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String strconverted = "MULTIPOINT Z (116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582,116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997)";
String temp = strconverted.substring(strconverted.indexOf("(") + 1, strconverted.indexOf(")"));
String[] strArray = temp.split(",");

// parts[0] =  "116.356887145739 39.887461162166 -28.1861667136582"
// parts[1] =  "116.374615732553 39.8883537940982 125.380505711997"
```